# Getting gpu vendor name on windows and linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, command, gpu

I'm currently writing some integration tests which should run on different physical machines and VMs with different OS.

For one type of test I have to find out if an nvidia-graphic card is installed on the running machine. I don't need any other information - only the vendor name (and it would be OK if I only knew if it is an NVIDIA graphic card or not - not interested in other vendors).

I can only use the python standard lib so I think the best way is to use subprocesses and using the shell.

Are there some commands for Windows(Win10x64) and Linux(Fedora, CentOS, SUSE) (without installing any tools or external libs) to find out the gpu vendor?

Comment: I guess you could use  the `lsmod` command and check if nouveau or nvidia_drm are loaded... You can also use `lspci` and grep for "NVIDIA".

Comment: If you're running X, I guess you could parse the X server log file -- assuming that you know where it is, on a particular system. I have `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, but that probably can't be assumed on other systems.

Comment: Thanks, lsmod is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following solution:

On Linux I'm using `lsmod` (or `/sbin/lsmod`; thanks to n00dl3) to see any occurence of "nvidia" and on Windows I'm using `wmic path win32_VideoController get name` to get some gpu information.